# Handling Version number - versioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, versioning

I am working on interface between my program with some recorded data files. My program will load up the data file and store it into database. In recorded data files, it has a format structure which contains different version numbers of other programs (which generated that files)

What is the best way to handle the version number?

> Major_Minor_Build_Revision
>
> 12.03.04.142

I would be using in my program to load all data later of specified version (eg. 2.03.04.142)

**Programming**

In Delphi, we could create a record and handle the version number:

```
TVersion = Record
   Major : integer;
   Minor : integer;
   Build : integer;
   Revision : integer;
end;
```

Or would it be better to do conversion into Integer and store it? If it is what's the best way to do conversion?

**Database**

Same thing in SQL database, we could create each columns for [Major], [Minor], [Build], [Revision] as integer to store it.

Or if we use version conversion, we could use only one column in SQL [Version].

Which one is the best way to use it? or Is there any better way to handle it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version number are you asking about? The IDE will already handle your version number for your project, and Windows has knowledge of major/minor/build/revision built into GetVersionInfo. Most modern software projects utilize the same version number definition. Why do you need a Delphi record to store what the IDE will already store in your executable and the WinAPI will already retrieve? How to store it in your DB would clearly be a matter only you can decide, as you're the one who would be updating and retrieving it. How do you intend to use it?

Comment: @sMah . . . The best way to store data is determined by how it is used.  Can you edit your question with some examples of how you would use the version number?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server- a relational database

Comment: From your usage scenario its still not clear which you want us alternative to advocate for :-) Do you plan to determine a relation between eq. `1.2` and `2.1`? Pack version to numeric type like http://pastebin.com/z3Jmk35M , then. By the way, signed version components gives me yikes.

Comment: You still didn't really say how you want the version to be used. What operations do you want to be able to perform on the version data on the server side? That is, how do you want to query the version info?

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server has lousy built-in support for parsing strings.  Hence, I would discourage you from storing the version *only* as a period delimited string.  If you do so, you will probably use the `PARSENAME()` function extensively.  And then, one day, if you had a fifth or sixth element to the version, nothing will work any more.

So, here are some alternatives:

- Create a reference table for versions.  This would have the same structure as the Delphi versioning, plus additional fields on what it should look like on output and an identity primary key.  The version in other tables would reference the value in this table.
- Store each of the four parts of the version in its own column, and manipulate the version using user-defined functions or computed columns.
- Create your own user defined type for a version.

I would tend to go for one of the first two options.

Answer (score -3):

I personally would use conversion to store this version number in a single Integer.

I would use a record as you have suggested. But instead of storing each version field in an Integer itself I would use Byte.

```
TVersion = Record
   Major : Byte;
   Minor : Byte;
   Build : Byte;
   Revision : Byte;
end;
```

Why use Byte fields instead of Integer? Because this gives you an excelent way of generating a single Integer to store the whole version number. Now since one Byte equals to 8 bits you can easily store four Byte fields in a single 32 bit Integer where the first field represents the first 8 bits, the second field represents the second 8 bits and so forth.

Now this does limits you in a way so that each version field can only have numbers from 0 to 255 but I think this would be more than enough. If not you can replace these Byte fields (8 bit integer) with SmallInt fields (16 bit Integer) and generate a 64 bit Integer to store the version information instead of 32 bit Integer that I originally suggested.

Now having version number stored in a single Integer, it also makes it much easier to determine in which version rage is a specific version.

For instance, let us say that you have a file generated with a program with version 1.52.45.75 and all files which were generated with that program with versions from 1.02.05.45 to 2.84.62.42 are build in specific way (contain specific fields, etc.), and you want to use a specific method for reading data from them.

If you store the version number in four seperate fields, you would probably try to do range checking for each of those four fields with a code similar to this:

```
if (MayorVersion => 1) and (MayorVersion =< 2) then
  if (MinorVersion => 2) and (MinorVersion =< 84) then
    if (Build => 5) and (Build =< 62) then
      if (Revision => 45) and (Revision =< 42) then //This looks wrong doesn't it
      begin
        //Process the file in certain way
      end;
```

Now if you take a close look at the code above you will see a problem in it. What is that problem? The revision part of the version information of the newest program that will process the file in a certain way is smaller than the revision part of the olderst program that will process it.

Now you would not have this problem if the whole version inforamtion would be stored in a single Integer as suggested above because you would now be doing comparison of the whole version information and not of a single version information fields one by one.

EDIT: As far as storing version information into database goes. I also think that storing single Integer which you generated from multiple version fields is better, because this way you can retrieve whole version information with one simple call. But it does prevent you from sorting the database entries by specific version fields. So if that is required, then the use of seperate fields might be more apropriate.

Comment: Better hope that nobody has a build number > 255. You don't get to choose the type here. It's defined by the system. In the case of Windows these four values are unsigned 16 bit values. What you also need to understand is that this is a question about DB storage rather than code. The code is infinitely malleable. Not so the DB.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If I understand corectly the OP is not talking about version information stored in Executable files which is defined by the system, but by version information that certain programs store in the files they create. And this version iformation may not be the same as the version information stored in executables so its type can be defined by the program itself. The reason why I focused on code side of the problem is becouse database side of the problem seems perfectly clear to me. And that is that it is better to store one converted value in single field. ...

Comment: ... Ask yourself this: What is better approach to store date into database in three fields (Day, Month, Year) or in one Date field. Version information isn't so much different than date type, or time type. Each of these is comprised by multiple fields but can be converted in single number.

Comment: If we are talking about what is to be stored in the database, why does your answer only consider Delphi code.

Comment: I gues I asumed that if my answer convinces the OP to use sugested approach at the code side he would do the same on the database side. Anywhay I have edited my answer to also cover the database side.

Comment: If you wish to pack into a single value then just use unsigned 64 bit integer

Comment: If you read my answer again you will see that I mention both options (using 32 bit integer when usinb Bytes for fields or 64 bit integer when using Small Integers for fields). So now it is up to OP about which approach he choses

Comment: If should be `Word` rather than `Smallint`. An unsigned type.

Comment: _you will see a problem in it._ which is easily solved with `if (Build => 5) and (Revision => 45) or (Build =< 62) and (Revision =< 42)` as fourth condition.

Comment: @NGLN `<=` and `>=` rather than `=<` and `=>`.

Comment: @David Omg, blindly copied! Another -1. For me as well ;)